# Yii2 change username on creation

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user, yii2-validation

I want my app to detect when a username is already taken and change it. In fact, when the user register himself he enter his last and first name and the username is lastName.firstName. How do I detect the username is already taken and how to change it (add a number for example) ?

Thanks.

Comment: So you are automatically providing username ?

Comment: Yes that's right, the user enter his last name and his first name and the username is given by the app.

Comment: Could you also share the code where  app determines the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should override `beforeValidate()` function, bellow is my sample code:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeValidate()
{
    /** your code here **/

    $isExist = static::find()->where(['username' => $this->username])->count();

    if($isExist){
        //Count total rows with the similar username
        $total = static::find()->where(['LIKE','username', "{$this->username}%"])->count();
        //We will add $total + 1 to the username so we have new unique username
        $this->username .= '-' . ($total+1); 
    }

    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I thought the validation was done in SignupForm model ?
static::findOne() is in the user model right ?

Comment: Correct, add this in the User model file which extends from ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

What is the user module you use? Is it `dektrium/yii2-user` module?

We can override the user model class and override `beforeValidate` function to detect and change the username before save.

Comment: Not I use the user basic model which extends Component in vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User

Comment: So you should override `beforeValidate` function.

Comment: Ok , I override the beforeValidate method but how can I detect the username is already taken ?

Comment: I posted another answer with my sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36711943/2688756